# How do I use Shopify BuButton.Js from a secure site

Tags: shopify, buybutton.js

This is the CDN that I am attempting to use:

```
<script src="http://sdks.shopifycdn.com/js-buy-sdk/v1/latest/index.umd.min.js"></script>
```

This source URL is not secure, but my website is, therefore, I am getting a mixed-content error when my site runs.  What is the solution to this problem? What am I missing here?

Comment: You can always change the source to just // and the browser will then get HTTPS if the current session is also HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Open the link [shopifycdn js](http://sdks.shopifycdn.com/js-buy-sdk/v1/latest/index.umd.min.js) and copy it into your own .js file with their copyright header included and use it. It has MIT license and therefore you can use it as your own.